# Setting arcpy.env.workspace to ArcSDE connection in separate module on ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server

I have problem defining arcpy.env.workspace in a separate module when publishing the script as a Geoprocessing Service on arcgis server

For instance:

**my main tool script:**

```
from myModule import myTool

workspace = "Database Connections\\GEOP011@demma18.sde"
tableName = "DEMMA18.MyTable"

myTool.execute(workspace, tableName)
```

**myModule.myTool:**

```
import arcpy

def execute(workspace, tableName)
    arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
    doSomething(tableName)

def doSomething(tableName)
     with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tableName, ["OBJECTID"]) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                  print(row)
```

When published to the server, this script will return error : cannot open DEMMA18.MyTable

However, if I put the same code in a single .py file it runs on the server without error. Any Idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you please include your entire error message including line numbers and any other python information

Comment: How do you specify `myTool` in myModule?  In your `tableName` what is `DEMMA18`?  What happens if you remove this so `tableName = "MyTable"`?

Comment: @Midavalo DEMMA18 is the schema name and it takes part of the table name as a convention in the database. The problem is well described by Ben S Nadler answer. I gave an answer on geonet forum: https://geonet.esri.com/message/637176-re-problem-settings-arcpyenvworkspace-to-sde-connection-in-separate-module-on-arcgis-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try referencing your full path, not through "database Connections"

The path "Database Connections/..." maps to a user folder. Other users will not have access. Use full paths in scripts.

There is also a issue with the copying enterprise workspace connections during publishing. The workaround is to place the connection file in a registered folder so that your ArcGIS Server has access to it.

Comment: `arcpy.Exists (r"DatabaseConnections\DB.sde")` will return `false` due to requiring space between "Database" and "Connections".  It should return `true` as `arcpy.Exists (r"Database Connections\DB.sde")`. However if a different user is trying to connect it will fail anyway as `Database Connections` is stored in user profile and so full path is still recommended.  I use a stand-alone folder specifically for all database connections then control permissions so that scripts and other users can still access them if allowed.  +1

Comment: There is something strange, I have to close/reopen ArcMap between every GP Service I want to publish to arcgis server when I use full path for the `arcpy.env.workspace`. If not, I got the `cannot open table` error. Any Idea why? The workspace is a SDE connection file in a location both desktop and server have access.

Comment: Is the error on the desktop or server logs?

Comment: It is on the server logs